# Setting a link dynamically for a vb.net project

Tags: vb.net, installation, database-connection, connection-string

I have created a project using Vb.net 2008 and I have created an installer for that.But I have hard coded the path to connect to the **Access database** using OLEDB.You must have seen the typical installation scenario where an installer installs the project to the location specified by the user and the software runs fine irrespective of the location where it is installed.

I wanted to know how I can achieve following two aspects

1)The Project gives an error **ERROR[IM014][Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager].The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the driver and Application after running the .exe file.**

2)How can I fix the above issue and set the path dynamically so that the application works fine irrespective of where it is installed

Please help

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using 'relative path' in the connection string rather than 'absolute path'. E.g. Instead of using 'C:\users\name\project\app\database\mydb.mdb', change it to '.\database\mydb.mdb' in the connection string. (Assuming the path before 'database' is application path). It had worked for me.

Regards.
Girish